# HttpWebRequest cookie for redirected request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

In my program I should authorize on the site, get authorization cookie value and send request to page (page1, which url like "mysite.com/lots/8188/request/4261/"), which redirect me to another (page2, which url like "mysite.com/lots/view/8188/"):

```
sendingRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                sendingRequest.CookieContainer.Add(sendingRequest.RequestUri, new Cookie(ASPNETSessionIdCookieName, this.ASPNETSessionIdCookie));
sendingRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                sendingRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendingRequest.GetResponse();
```

Ok, page1 return me expected HTTP 302 Page with expected url of page2, then sendingRequest go to page2, but it don't send ASPNETSessionIdCookieName cookie to page2 and server return me uncorrect response.
How can I use "ASPNETSessionIdCookieName" for redirected request?

Answer (score 0):

The auto-redireciton will follow the cookies domain/URI to check if the cookies should be sent again, once the URL is changing I believe the problem is the first parameter of the `CookieContainer.Add`.

You're restricting the cookie to the first page URL.

Try change for something like this:

```
sendingRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(ASPNETSessionIdCookieName, this.ASPNETSessionIdCookie));
```

If you want to restrict the cookie only to that domain you can them use `Cookie` four parameters constructor.